# How to fill in a UK visa application form if you have no surname on your passport?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, passports, standard-visitor-visas

I do not have a surname in my passport.
How do I enter 'Given Name' and 'Family Name' in my UK visa application form?

Comment: Adding what culture your full name style comes from may be helpful in providing a useful answer. [Sadly it has been a slow process to shift world wide bureaucracies over to some kind of 'universal name format' that reliably covers all the options.]

Comment: In my passport there is no surname only given name but i cannot leave surname blank in visa application what to write there?

Comment: @TheLuckless RE: "'universal name format' that reliably covers all the options", see this classic article: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 9):

There is an answer here http://www.immigrationboards.com/uk-tier-1-post-study-work-visas/no-surname-to-enter-online-dependent-visa-application-t122774.html from 2013 that indicates entering ‘-‘ is acceptable.

> I had a similar issue with my wife’s passport. I had put '-' in the surname field.
>
> Visa was granted by the high commission in Chennai. In the receipt her name was 'firstname' 'firstname'.  However on the visa her name was only 'firstname'
>
> She recently came to the UK, and there were no issues in immigration etc, except that the Indian immigration authority suggested that I include my name in my wife's passport.