# How to apply for UK visa with First Name Unknown?

Tags: visas, uk

What is the way to apply for a UK visa if your first name is unknown (FNU) in your passport and the field is mandatory?

How should one go about applying for one?

Comment: This https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143159/how-to-fill-in-a-uk-visa-application-form-if-you-have-no-surname-on-your-passpor/144113#144113 refers to not having a family name but I’d imagine the principle is the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As traveller has posted in their comment, the process would be the same as those who have applied without a last name. The UK visa department has dealt with this issue many times, and will have a process to follow when they see this. In the place of first name, simply put a '-'.

A similar issue was discussed [here](http://www.immigrationboards.com/uk-tier-1-post-study-work-visas/no-surname-to-enter-online-dependent-visa-application-t122774.html) and commentators have had success with putting '-' in the box for last name, similarly people have put N/A or other statements to indicate there is no last name for the applicant have also been successful. Please see below for one such example:

> I had a similar issue with my wife’s passport. I had put '-' in the
>   surname field.
>
> Visa was granted by the high commission in Chennai. In the receipt her
>   name was 'firstname' 'firstname'. However on the visa her name was
>   only 'firstname'
>
> She recently came to the UK, and there were no issues in immigration
>   etc.